# jQuery - 2 sortable lists: How to add a removed li back to list 1

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have two sortable unordered lists and a trash can. Users are taking items from list1 and dropping them in list2. They can also remove items from list2 by dragging and dropping them over a trash can div. All of this works fine, but now I'd like to add the dropped ("trashed") list item back to list1.

I'm using ASP.NET, so the ul controls are getting their list items in the code behind.

Any help is appreciated.

```
$('#<%= list1.ClientID %>, #<%= list2.ClientID %>').sortable({
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            storeAndUpdateGroupItems();
        },
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable, #trashCan"
    }).disableSelection();

    $('#trashCan').droppable({
        accept: '#<%= list2.ClientID %> li',
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $('#<%= list1.ClientID %>').append(ui.draggable); //problem...
            ui.draggable.remove();
            storeAndUpdateGroupItems();
        }
    });
```

If I add ui.draggable.html() to the .append() method the html gets added back into list1, but I'm trying to add the actual draggable, sortable li back to list1.

And the HTML

```
<td>
        <div class="availableCoins">
            <ul id="_ulAllItems" runat="server" class="connectedSortable">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="selectedCoins">
            <ul id="_ul" runat="server" class="connectedSortable">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="removeItem">
        <div id="trashCan">
    </td>
```

**EDIT** OK, I got this working. I feel like it's kind of "hacky." I just rebuilt the li using the ui.draggable.html(). It works, and after the item is added back to list1 it's draggable and sortable. Thanks for the suggestions.

```
$('#trashCan').droppable({
    accept: '#<%= list2.ClientID %> li',
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $('#<%= list1.ClientID %>').append("<li class='dragItem'>" + ui.draggable.html() + "</li>");
        ui.draggable.remove();
        storeAndUpdateGroupItems();
    }
});
```

Comment: Just a quick thought, and I'm not sure I get it, but try using detach() instead of remove() if you plan on reusing the element.

Comment: @adeneo - that might come in handy. I'll still have to figure out how to reuse it :). I was thinking that if I added it back to list1 before removing it, I could avoid a null reference (because it was removed ie no longer existed.

Comment: you don't need `ui.draggable.remove();` since you've just appended it which moves it in the DOM

Comment: @lnrbob - I'm not sure I understand. The ui.draggable.remove() removes the li from list2 - which is what I want. I'm trying to append the li to list1, and remove it from list2.

Comment: if you append an existing element to another element it moves it, it doesn't duplicate it

Comment: @lnrbob - I see what you're saying. So once I get this append() part working, I can disregard the remove() method.

Comment: yup. The problem as I see it is that you need to have a drop event on each area which moves the element and then reinitiates the sortable effect. My personal preference is to not actually move anything, use checkboxes to indicate selection (i.e. trash or not) and clone elements to keep the visuals the same. Might be overkill but I prefer it...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sortable("refresh") method to update the sortable items in a list.

> $('#YourSortableList').sortable("refresh");

I'm not sure if what I did below is exactly the behavior you're after, but hopefully it'll put you in the right direction.

```
$('#_ulAllItems, #_ul').sortable({
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        //storeAndUpdateGroupItems();
    },
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable, #trashCan"
}).disableSelection();

$('#trashCan').droppable({
    accept: '#_ul li',
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        console.log(ui.draggable);
        $('#_ulAllItems').append(ui.draggable);
        ui.draggable.remove();

        //Added refresh statement below
        $('#_ulAllItems').sortable("refresh");
        //storeAndUpdateGroupItems();
    }
});
```

See my jsfiddle code here: http://jsfiddle.net/kjqxc/

See the jQuery UI documentation for more information:http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-refresh

Comment: Not exactly but it does give me an idea. I may have to call the method in my code behind that builds list1 aka "refreshes" it after I move the li to the trash.